# button function not read when inside app.component.ts

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, angular6

This is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Code Concrete</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="btn-test">Click this!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.component.ts

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="content-wrapper">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>asd</h2>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="btn-test">Click this! 
    </button>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-messages></app-messages>
  </section>
</div>
```

I have a scipt custom.js included in angular.json (formerly angular-cli.json).

custom.js

```
$('button#btn-test').on('click',function() {
    alert("success");
});
```

I have also jquery and bootstrap styles and scripts included in angular.json.

The button was working when inside index.html but when i transferred it into app.component.html, it won't work anymore. Why is the button not working? Did I miss any line of codes? Do I need to import anything else when I've already included my scripts and styles in angular.json?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the button is not on the page when jQuery kicks in. Move the call inside the app.component.ts, after **ngAfterViewInit()**. But better - don't use jQuery at all in angular, especially when the logic can be easily achieved using angular by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it directly in Angular? With a Property Binding like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="btn-test" (click)="method()">Click this! 
</button>
```

In the typescript file do the following:

```
method() {
alert('success');
}
```